# Как обернуть запрос xacml XML

Tags: c#, xml

Есть шаблон запроса

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xacml-samlp:XACMLAuthzDecisionQuery
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_4019b6ca-e8de-4f3383cb-ec5ab73ec4df" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-12T14:25:12.5340114Z"
    xmlns:xacml-samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol:wd14">
    <xacml-context:Request ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false"
        xmlns:xacml-context="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
            <xacml-context:Content>
                <n3:Identifier тип="Type1"
                    xmlns:n3="urn:example.ru:n3:2017-04-10">
                    <n3:System oid="urn:oid:1.2.3">
                        <n3:sn номер="123" />
                        <n3:fio фамилия="Ivanov" имя="Ivan" отчество="Ivanovich" />
                    </n3:System>
                </n3:Identifier>
            </xacml-context:Content>
        </xacml-context:Attributes>
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject" />
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:intermediary-subject">
            <xacml-context:Content>
                <n3:Identifier тип="Type2"
                    xmlns:n3="urn:example.ru:test:n3:2017-05-04">
                    <n3:System oid="urn:oid:1.2.3.4.5.6.2.1.1.12">
                        <n3:Организация oid="urn:oid:1.2.3.4" />
                    </n3:System>
                </n3:Identifier>
            </xacml-context:Content>
        </xacml-context:Attributes>
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:codebase">
            <xacml-context:Content>
                <n3:Identifier тип="SYS_MED"
                    xmlns:n3="urn:example.ru:zzzz:n3:2017-05-04">
                    <n3:System oid="urn:oid:1.2.3.2.9.1.2">
                        <n3:ISM oid="urn:oid:9090" />
                    </n3:System>
                </n3:Identifier>
            </xacml-context:Content>
        </xacml-context:Attributes>
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:requesting-machine" />
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
            <xacml-context:Content>
                <n3:Identifier тип="pat"
                    xmlns:n3="urn:example.ru:trypares:n3:2017-05-04">
                    <n3:System oid="urn:oid:1.2.60.2.6.1.1.4">
                        <n3:IdGlobal value="IdGlobal" />
                    </n3:System>
                </n3:Identifier>
            </xacml-context:Content>
        </xacml-context:Attributes>
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
            <xacml-context:Content>
                <n3:Identifier тип="action"
                    xmlns:n3="urn:example.ru:yy:n3:2017-05-04">
                    <n3:System oid="urn:oid:1.2.643.2.69.1.1.4">
                        <n3:Метод имя="читать" />
                    </n3:System>
                </n3:Identifier>
            </xacml-context:Content>
        </xacml-context:Attributes>
        <xacml-context:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment" />
    </xacml-context:Request>
</xacml-samlp:XACMLAuthzDecisionQuery>
```

Необходимо сформировать такой XML как указан выше. Для формирования данной XML я использовал библиотеку `Abc.Xacml` из Nuget. Однако у меня получилось сформировать лишь `<xacml-context:Request` со всеми внутренностями. Но обернуть все это в

```
<xacml-samlp:XACMLAuthzDecisionQuery
        xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_4019b6ca-e8de-4f3383cb-ec5ab73ec4df" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-05-12T14:25:12.5340114Z"
        xmlns:xacml-samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol:wd14">


</xacml-samlp:XACMLAuthzDecisionQuery>
```

у меня не получается.

Планируется что данная XML будет переведена в `base64` и отправлена по http.

Вопрос в том как обернуть `xacml-context:Request` в `xacml-samlp:XACMLAuthzDecisionQuery` ?

Comment: разве в `System.Xml` нет нужного функционала?

Comment: @dgzargo Добавить руками конечно можно, но хотелось бы формировать через библиотеку для единообразия